# Install specific PHP version on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I need to install a specific PHP version (**8.1.22**) to use with Apache and Mysql.

I tried:

```
apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

But it installs the following:

```
with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Any guidance?

Comment: The only realistic way to do this – in a reliable fashion – is to use a Docker container. You can then pull the exact version of PHP that you need. Your Apache configuration will need to be set up to proxy the request.

Comment: Do you have any reason to need the exact patch release version (i.e. the third number)? In general the need to do this is rare because there are no API changes, only bug fixes, in these versions. You can choose a minor version using `apt`, although it ignores the patch release and grabs the latest one, such as `apt install php8.1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard getting the exact PHP `8.1.22` version. However, if you are OK with something close to it, `8.1.24` is the current version at `ppa:ondrej/php`.

- Remove your current PHP 8.1:

  ```
  sudo apt remove php8.1
  ```
- Install ondrej's repo:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt update
  ```
- Install PHP 8.1:

  ```
  sudo apt install php8.1
  ```
- Disable the default PHP 8.2 in Ubuntu 22.04:

  ```
  sudo a2dismod php8.2
  ```
- Enable PHP 8.1:

  ```
  sudo a2enmod php8.1
  ```
- Restart the Apache:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be - uninstall the official version and find some alternative package.
[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=jammy](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=jammy)

This seems really problematic that the PHP version isn't raised to the latest bugfix version. On Ubuntu 22.04 the version 8.1.2 is included but the latest version is 8.1.24 - 1 and 3/4 of a year old.
I found this out while researching why my installation is consuming so much memory: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8646
So the bug is probably already fixed.